# How get to the latest 50 files in a folder based on the file creation time

Tags: java, file, java-8, comparator, file-sorting

I have a folder containing thousands of files. I plan to read the latest 50 files based on the date created, Java by default reading files created oldest, comparing each file taking lot of time, is there a better way to do this?

I have a Folder `\usr\documents\archive` have 1000 files in it
want to read 50 documents in the folder based on the file creation.

Comment: What operating system are you using? How do you know when the files were created? Based on filename? Last modified time? ... Your best bet is to skip java and just use the tools the OS/Linux distro gives you.

Comment: *comparing each file taking lot of time* - comparing what?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following to get creation or last modification time

```
  BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(path, BasicFileAttributes.class);
    FileTime fileTime = attr.creationTime();
```

OR

```
 FileTime creationTime = (FileTime) Files.getAttribute(path, "creationTime");
```

Now since you can take creation time (or last modification time), you can sort files by creation time.

Caution: Iterating each file/directory will take time but it depends on your use case. I would do it if task is running in background but not for operation where user is waiting.  I would use cache to periodically process and store result for user facing operations.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a method that reads all files within a specified directory (folder) path and sorts the files based on creation (or modification) timestamps in either Ascending or Descending Order. A String[] Array is returned with either just the file names or path and filenames depending what is supplied within the methods optional (varArg) parameters.

```
/**
 * Returns a String[] Array of all the files within the supplied directory
 * (folder) in either Ascending or Descending order. By default the full
 * absolute path and the file name are returned, not just the file name.
 * <p>
 * If you want the files list to be sorted in Descending Order the supply
 * <b>1</b> within the optional <b>sortOrder</b> parameter.
 * <p>
 * If you want just the file names within the String[] Array then supply
 * <b>1</b>
 * within the optional <b>fileNamesOnly</b> parameter.
 * <p>
 * <b>Example Usage:</b><pre>
 *  {@code     String folderPath = "C:\\Log Files\\SpecificAppLogsFolder";
 *       String[] logFiles = getFolderFilesInOrder(folderPath);
 *       for (String s : logFiles) {
 *           System.out.println(s);
 *       }
 *   }</pre>
 *
 * @param folderPath (String) The full path to the file system directory
 *                   (folder) in which you want to get the list of files
 *                   from.<br>
 *
 * @param options    (Optional - int):<pre>
 *
 *      sortOrder       - Default is 0 (Ascending Order) which means the files
 *                        list will ne returned in ascending sort order (from 
 *                        the oldest files to the newest files). If any
 *                        value other than 0 (ie: 1) is supplied then the files
 *                        list will be returned in descending order (from newest
 *                        files to oldest files).
 *
 *      fileNamesOnly   - Default is 0 where Path and file name are returned within
 *                        the String[] Array. If any value other than 0 (ie: 1)
 *                        is supplied then only the file names itself will be
 *                        returned within the String[] Array.
 *
 *                        If an argument is supplied to this optional parameter
 *                        then something MUST also be supplied to the optional
 *                        <b>sortOrder</b> parameter (either 0 or 1).</pre>
 *
 * @return (One Dimensional String Array) The files contained within the
 *         supplied directory path in the desired sort order based on their
 *         Creation (last modified) timestamp.
 */
public String[] getFolderFilesInOrder(String folderPath, int... options) {
    File folder = new File(folderPath);
    if (!folder.exists() && !folder.isDirectory()) {
        System.err.println("Either the supplied folder doesn't exist "
                + "or it is not a directory!");
        return null;
    }
    int sortOrder = 0;      // Default - Ascending Order | any value other than 0 for Descending Order.
    int fileNamesOnly = 0;  // Default - Path & file name | any value other than 0 for file names only.
    if (options.length >= 1) {
        sortOrder = options[0];
        if (options.length >= 2) {
            fileNamesOnly = options[1];
        }
    }

    File[] folderFilesList = folder.listFiles();
    if (sortOrder == 0) {
        Arrays.sort(folderFilesList, Comparator.comparingLong(File::lastModified));
    }
    else {
        Arrays.sort(folderFilesList, Comparator.comparingLong(File::lastModified).reversed());
    }

    List<String> filesList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (File f : folderFilesList) {
        if (f.isFile()) {
            filesList.add(fileNamesOnly == 0 ? f.getAbsolutePath() : f.getName());
        }
    }
    return filesList.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

How you might use this method could be like this:

```
/* Get all files (file names only) within the supplied directory path 
       (no sub-directories are processed) and sort them in descending order 
       (newest to oldest) based on creation (modification) timestamp and 
       return them in a String[] Array.                         */
String[] allFiles = getFolderFilesInOrder("C:/MyLogFilesDirectory", 1, 1);
    
// The number of files desired from the directory:
int numberOfFilesDesired = 50;
    
/* Just in case (for some reason) the supplied directory path
   does not contain the desired number of files.       */
numberOfFilesDesired = Math.min(numberOfFilesDesired, allFiles.length);
    
// Retrieve the number of files we want.
String[] desiredFiles = new String[numberOfFilesDesired];
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfFilesDesired; i++) {
    desiredFiles[i] = allFiles[i];
        
    //You can omit the line below. It's just for demo purposes:
    System.out.println((i+1) + ") " + desiredFiles[i]);
}
```